# How can I change img within 'a' tag when hover?

Tags: html, css

I have an `img` inside the `a` tag. When hovering on `a`, I want to change the image url. Is it possible with `CSS`?

```
<a  href="#"><img  src="img/takipet.png" alt=""></a>
```

Comment: This is trivial with CSS, but there are a few different approaches. We'll need more information on what you want to achieve (e.g. are background images ok? What determines the new image and can it be in the markup?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few ways to do this.

If you prefer to use css you should replace  with **background-image** property

```
a.some_class{
  background-image:url(your_image_url);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;      
  height:image_height;
  width:image_width;
}

a.some_class:hover{
   background-image:url(your_image_url2);
}
```

Also you can use two images wrapped with Div. And show/hide needed on div hover.

With jQuery

```
$('a img.your_img_class').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).attr("src", "hover_1_src");
})
.mouseout(function () {
    $(this).attr("src", "old_src");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer your question, here’s one CSS-only approach:

HTML:

```
<div id="the-image-wrapper">
  <img id="image-main" src="some/src">
  <img id="image-alternate" src="some/other/src">
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#image-alternate {display: none;}
#the-image-wrapper:hover #image-main {display: none;}
#the-image-wrapper:hover #image-alternate {display: inline;}
```

You’re probably better off trying an alternate approach however, such as using a background image instead. Of course, it really depends on the application.

If you’re going the background-image route, you should [take a look at using sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

Answer (score 1):

If it's a background image, you can do this:

```
.element:hover{
    background-image:url(bg.jpg);
}
```

or even

```
.element:hover a{
    background-image:url(bg.jpg);
}
```

If the `a` tag is within something else.

Answer (score 0):

Change `src=""` attribute is can't change by Using CSS . Just Change with Javascript Or Jquery.
you can Just Control Styles By css .

Create Div Element And set background-image for it.

HTML Css:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
<style>
#MyDiv{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-image: url('Image.jpg');
}
#MyDiv:hover{
background-image: url('NewImage.jpg');
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="MyDiv" > </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Html Javascript:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/images/logo-jquery.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png';" >
</body>
</html>
```